# Mapping and [Any] to array with struct model in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I have an array

```
var threatsArrayVariable: [Any]
```

with the value like this

```
[{
   info = "/bin/bash";
   name = 1;
   threatTypeId = 1000;
}, {
   info = "com.openssh.sshd";
   name = 24;
   threatTypeId = 2000;
}]
```

how to convert this array into an array with struct?

```
struct ThreatsModel: Codable {
   let info: String
   let name: Int
   let threatTypeId: Int
}
```

Comment: It's not `[Any]`, it's `[[String:Any]]`. Where does this array come from? If it is JSON, you can decode it directly to `[ThreatsModel].self`. If it's not JSON then first encode it with `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: The array's from SDK and it's from a func 
func threatScan(_ threatsArray: [Any]!) { }

Comment: Then use `map` or `compactMap` on the array

Comment: That's the print of a `[NSDictionary]`, it's using Swift print for the `Array` (the opening `[` and closing `]`), and Open Step Format for each dictionary (default format printing for a `NSDictionary`, Objective-C "legacy"). It can be casted into a `[[String: Any]]`, and you can use a `map`/`compactMap`  on it to transform it into a `[ThreatsModel]`. I'd suggest to add to `ThreadsModel` a `init(withDict: [String: Any])` for more clarity.

Comment: @Larme can you give me example code for this, I'm new at mapping array. thankyou

Comment: You can use a simple for loop if you don't know how to use `map`/`compactMap` yet... There is nothing wrong with that.